Are all descendants of Client Component client components? Nextjs app router
the doc says that "use client" is a boundary between server and client.
Does it mean once i use "use client" then all descendants are client components?
when I use framer-motion,I can't get benefit of server component, right?
you guys how do you think about it? or have some solution or I'm wrong?
When animating a component, I do the following. or to use custom hooks
// anim.ts

"use client"
export AnimationDiv=motion.div

// any server component

<AnimationDiv>
  <ComponetA/>
</AnimationDiv>

even if ComponentA itself can be server component, I use AnimationDiv of client component as its parent, so ComponentA wold behave as a Client Component, right?
and when I use   as a parent of page.tsx, whole the page would be client component.
it is not performance problem?
